# adding a fragment to existing ViewGroup, programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to add a new fragment to current ViewGroup without creating a `<fragment>` in my main layout, so I did these:
created a new java class as a Fragment subclass and also created its layout "R.layout.fraglayout":

```
public class FragOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglayout, container, false);
    }
}
```

now as API's guide said I should add this new fragment to the ViewGroup, so I did this using `FragmentTransaction` and added it to main_activity's onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //adding the fragment
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    FragOne newFrag = new FragOne();
    ft.add(R.layout.activity_main, newFrag);
    ft.commit();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

the code is not working and here is my question:
The documentation said I should add my fragment to the current "ViewGroup" by I guess I'm adding it to the Layout. Are those same? If not, what is the ViewGoup id then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ViewGroup` id is, for example, the id of a `FrameLayout` in your `Activity` layout, R.layout.activity_main.

When using transaction.add(). pass the `FrameLayout` id as first parameter.

One more thing, call setContentView() right after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and only then load your Fragment. Like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//adding the fragment
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

FragOne newFrag = new FragOne();
ft.add(R.id.myContainerFrameLayout, newFrag);
ft.commit();
```

}

Comment: thanks it solves the problem but I didn't get the last part. after adding the fragment to ViewGroup does it matter when you add 'setContentView'? both worked of course

Comment: @Aaron calling setContentView() earlier protects you from making mistakes like trying to setText() on a TextView belonging to that layout. You will get an Exception since the layout does not exist yet. So, just to be safer, declare it earlier. :D